# ViewModelViewHost requests a view when Remote Desktop connects

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have an existing project that implements a RoutedViewHost, and once bootstrapped it navigates to a ViewModel, and uses splat to resolve the View. This is working, however I noticed that when I remote desktop to a computer with an instance of the application running, upon connection the View is resolved again, then once more when the connection is broken by logging in locally again.

I have been able to reproduce this in a simple example using just a ViewModelViewHost (no router needed). Why does the view get recreated when remote desktop connects (or more precisely, why does the view get resolved more than once), and how can this be better managed? Note that the symptom does not present itself when the computer is simply locked/unlocked.

Simple example below.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ReactiveUiRemoteDesktopIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:reactiveUi="http://reactiveui.net"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <reactiveUi:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding DefaultViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;
using Splat;

namespace ReactiveUiRemoteDesktopIssue
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Locator.CurrentMutable.Register<ExamplePageViewModel>(() => new ExamplePageViewModel());
            Locator.CurrentMutable.Register<IViewFor<ExamplePageViewModel>>(() => new ExamplePageView());

            DefaultViewModel = Locator.Current.GetService<ExamplePageViewModel>();
        }

        [Reactive]
        public object DefaultViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ExamplePageViewModel.cs:

```
namespace ReactiveUiRemoteDesktopIssue
{
    public class ExamplePageViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

ExamplePageView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReactiveUiRemoteDesktopIssue.ExamplePageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ExamplePageView.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace ReactiveUiRemoteDesktopIssue
{
    public partial class ExamplePageView : IViewFor<ExamplePageViewModel>
    {
        public ExamplePageView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(ExamplePageViewModel), typeof(ExamplePageView),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public ExamplePageViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (ExamplePageViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = (ExamplePageViewModel)value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put the parsed part in OnStartup of app.xaml.cs, similar to the following
code,In this way, viewModelHost will find the view bound to ViewModel and parse it out：

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //register module(include view and viewmodel)
        builder.RegisterModule<MainModule>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        using (var scope=container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.UseSerilogFullLogger();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.Register<IViewFor<TestViewModel>>(() => new TestView());
            scope.Resolve<RegisterView>().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the relevance of this answer. The code example I provided was a minimum requirement to reproduce the issue described. Moving this to the OnStartup changes nothing, it just adds complexity to a simple example. To be clear, the question is "Why does the view get recreated when remote desktop connects (or more precisely, why does the view get resolved more than once), and how can this be better managed?"